# Using generics for resolving a collection name from a string

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, abstraction

I have some collections in a mongo DB: `autocomplete.brands` and `autocomplete.makes`

Each of these collections have items based on the same pattern that have a `Name` property:

```
public class AutocompleteEntity
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; } = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();

    [BsonElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Culture")]
    public string Culture { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to use generics for searching in each of these collections, here is what I have.

The high-level service using repositories:

```
public class AutocompleteHandler : IAutocompleteHandler
{
    private readonly IAutocompleteRepository<Brands> _brandsRepository;
    private readonly IAutocompleteRepository<Makes> _makesRepository;

    public AutocompleteHandler(
        IAutocompleteRepository<Brands> brandsRepository,
        IAutocompleteRepository<Makes> makesRepository
        )
    {
        _brandsRepository = brandsRepository;
        _makesRepository = makesRepository;
    }

    public async Task<ICollection<string>> SearchForBrand(string name, string culture)
    {
        return await _brandsRepository.Search(name, culture);
    }

    public async Task<ICollection<string>> SearchForMake(string name, string culture)
    {
        return await _makesRepository.Search(name, culture);
    }
}
```

For this to work I defined a class for each repository type:

```
public interface IAutocompleteCollection
{
}

public class Brands : IAutocompleteCollection
{
}

public class Makes : IAutocompleteCollection
{
}
```

and the generic repository:

```
public class AutocompleteRepository<T> : IAutocompleteRepository<T> where T : IAutocompleteCollection
{
    private readonly IMongoCollection<AutocompleteEntity> _collection;

    public AutocompleteRepository(IMongoTenantResolver mongoResolver)
    {
        var name = typeof(T).Name;
        var collectionName = $"autocomplete.{char.ToLowerInvariant(name[0]) + name.Substring(1)}";

        _collection = mongoResolver
            .GetMongoDbInstance()
            .GetCollection<AutocompleteEntity>(collectionName);
    }

    public async Task<List<string>> Search(string name, string culture)
    {
        var filter = Builders<AutocompleteEntity>.Filter.Regex("Name", new BsonRegularExpression(name, "i"));
        filter &= Builders<AutocompleteEntity>.Filter.Eq("Culture", culture);
        var data = await _collection.FindAsync(filter);
        var items = await data.ToListAsync();
        return items.Select(i => i.Name).ToList();
    }
}
```

### My question

I am using the empty classes `Brands` and `Makes` in order to be able to resolve the collection by name in the generic repository:

```
var name = typeof(T).Name;
var collectionName = $"autocomplete.{char.ToLowerInvariant(name[0]) + name.Substring(1)}";
```

Is there a more elegant way to use generics without relying on empty classes/interface or is that the best way to use generics in my case?

### Update1 :

After @RobertHarvey 's answer, I am adding this information. Generics usage is useful to me because I am using Dependency Injection and thus I can have this one-liner in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IAutocompleteRepository<>), typeof(AutocompleteRepository<>));
```

I can then add many other autocomplete types without the need to register them individually in the Startup. Also because of DI usage, I am not sure how I can inject an enum value into the constructor.

Comment: This is strongly typed with generics, but you never actually use the type for anything other than the name. Instead of using generics, you could just pass the collection name as a parameter in the repository's constructor

Comment: Thanks @AndrewWilliamson I updated my question to describe why I am using generics and how I am not sure if I can inject an enum value in the constructor.

Comment: I see. You could make derived repository classes, e.g. `BrandsAutocompleteRepository`, which provide the correct value to the base constructor, but this means you'd also have to make a derived interface and then you're back to registering one at a time. You could make a `AutocompleteRepositoryFactory`, which has a `GetRepository(CollectionName name)` method, and inject that instead of injecting the individual repositories. You could just update the `Search(string name, string culture)` method to take the CollectionName as well, then you only need one instance of `AutocompleteRepository`

Comment: I think the last option is probably the tidiest

Answer (score 2):

```
public enum CollectionName
{
    Brands,
    Makes
}

// Constructor
public AutoCompleteRepository(IMongoTenantResolver resolver, CollectionName name)
{
    // Name of collection is name.ToString().  Preserves static type checking,
    // avoids empty classes and interfaces.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that I am using Dependency Injection and thus I don't see how I can use an enum in the constructor? Also using generics is nice because I can use this one liner in the Startup.cs: `services.AddTransient(typeof(IAutocompleteRepository<>), typeof(AutocompleteRepository<>));` and add other autocomplete types without having to remember having to add them to the Startup too

Comment: Which DI container are you using?

Comment: the default one in .NET Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceprovider